# Is it possible to assign a "nmcli" connection profile on any newly created network interface without user intervention?

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, nmcli

We have enforced certificate authentication on our corporate wired (and wireless) network. Windows devices are easy to configure... However, Linux workstations running Ubuntu 20.04 and some 22.04 are a bit more challenging!

I have deployed a script that adds a network connection profile to each connected network interface using "nmcli connection add". This is working fine... for all present interfaces when the script is executed!
But we have docking stations with ethernet ports in the company. If the dock isn't plugged in when executing the script, then the connection profile is not applied, and users complain about it.

Is there a way to detect whenever a new network interface is added to the system, and execute the nmcli command at this time?
Or even better... Is there a way to set a default connection profile that would be applied first whatever the interface could be?

Thanks in advance!